# Possible tiling patterns for equiangular hexagon with alternating side lengths

Tags: geometry, packing-problem, tiling

I want to make a pattern of an equiangular hexagons with side lengths of 1-5-1-5-1-5. Here are 3 examples I made:

[image: 1-5 hexagons with six-pointed stars included]
[image: 1-5 hexagons with regular hexagons included]
[image: 1-5 hexagons with triangles included]

Which different patterns exist? Are there more than the ones I show? And which one is the most space-efficient, so that it minimizes the wasted space between the hexagons?

I checked the wikipedia page on [hexagonal tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling) but I cannot find examples for this specific hexagon.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you will not be able to reduce wasted space below the current, uh ... 3/49? that it currently is.

Comment: @DanUznanski: I agree that the most space-efficient tiling with the shown hexagon is $46/49$ (about 93.88% efficient; would leave small empty hexagons inside each group of six hexagons) -- basically equilateral triangle tiling (as is typical for hexagonal tilings) -- but OP's example is less efficient: each group of six hexagons has an inner hole of $6/49$ ($1/49$ per hexagon), which means Stijn's example is only .. umm.. $46/(49+1) = 23/25$ = 92% efficient?

Comment: What is your definition of “pattern”? Does it have to be periodic? Periodic in two independent directions? [Isohedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isohedral_figure) (which your example pattern seems to be)? [Isogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_figure) (which your first example is not)? [Isotoxal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotoxal_figure) (which the first example isn't either)? Aligned to multiples of $60°$? Judging from your pictures I'd assume you'd want isohedral tilings.

Comment: Both designs 1 and 2 have the same efficiency of 46/49, right?

Comment: @MvG - I just need the pattern to be "tileable", I'm not sure what isohedral, isogonal and isotoxal mean. Alignment doesn't matter and it doesn't have to be periodic. Do you know of such patterns that are non-periodic or have non-60° allignment?

Comment: @Stijn: Have you noticed that the terms you didn't understand were links to Wikipedia? I could take a group of 7 hexagons, arrange them randomly, take the enclosing axis-aligned rectangle and tile the plane with that in the obvious way. The result would be periodic, non-isohedral and unaligned. And pretty boring, mathematically speaking, sinice it had very little structure worth investigating. I recall *Tilings and Patterns* by Grünbaum & Shephard had long lists and figures of possible tilings. Myself I'm more involved with ornaments instead of tilings.

Comment: @MvG - Yes I clicked the wikipedia links but am sligthly overwhelmed by the mathematical terms. In principle, any pattern can go, though indeed I'm not looking for the "boring" patterns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the patterns I could think of, represented by their unit cells and with their densities listed beside:

[image: 1/5 hexagon tilings]

The first tiling shown in the question has no code in my diagram and has density $\frac{46}{49}=0.9388$. This is not very interesting because it is a rearrangement of the A0 tiling (the second in the question), which has the same density.

From the A0 tiling we can shift the hexagons on their long edges by one to five units to create the A1 to A5 tilings. As the holes between the tiles grow, so does the density decrease:

- A1 has density $\frac{23}{26}=0.8846$
- A2 has density $\frac{46}{61}=0.7541$
- A3 has density $\frac{23}{38}=0.6053$
- A4 has density $\frac{46}{97}=0.4742$
- A5 has density $\frac{23}{62}=0.3710$

The B tiling is the last one shown in the question and has density $\frac{23}{27}=0.8519$.

Now to answer the question of densest possible tiling. When I started typing this I thought it was tiling M, which has density $\frac{23}{24}=0.9583$ and features rows of tiles that can slide over each other.

[image: Tiling M]

Then I realised the rows could be pushed into each other a bit more, resulting in the *real* winner: tiling N with density $\frac{46}{47}=0.9787$.

[image: Tiling N]

So if you want to tile a real wall or floor with this shape, your best bets are tilings M and N. While M is less dense, it isn't chiral like N, and its rows may make it better suited to the (usually) rectangular areas tiles are supposed to cover.

Comment: Wow, nice, I didn't think it was possible to get this dense!

Comment: @Stijn Since you found it nice, you are encouraged to click the tick next to my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm a bit new here. I guess your answer would also work for hexagons with another ratio than 1:5, right?

Comment: @Stijn Sure, it can be extended to hexagons of other ratio. As (short side length)/(long side length) goes to 0 the tiling approaches triangular; as it goes to 1 the tiling approaches hexagonal.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong.  Good thing, too, that would have been boring.  What software did you make the drawings in?

Comment: @DanUznanski Inkscape. The same program I use to draw ponies (see my profile).